# How is world to map coordinate determined?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In autoware world-map is defined in a launch file.

I was curious as to how these coordinates are determined in first place? for instance in demo bag and associated data they are defined as

14771 84757 -39 0 0 0 for static transform.

I am guessing these are UTM coordinates with 0 0 0 for roll pitch and yaw.

In utilities I do see a node defined in map_tf_generator.cpp which finds (negative)average of the map points. Is this used to fill values in launch file?

And isn't the map generated in base_link frame?  or is it generated in some other frame?

Any explanation or pointing of documentation in this regard would be helpful.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332934/how-is-world-to-map-coordinate-determined?/) by [villie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34935/villie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you generate a map, each frame of the map is created using the origin of the `/base_link` frame but the combined PCD map (from `ndt_mapping`) is broadcast using the `/map` frame since it is a fixed frame and `/base_link` is not. The `/world` frame is assumed to be in MGRS (Japanese Rectangular Plane) coordinates and the origin of the `/map` frame (in the PCD map) is some offset from the origin of the MGRS plane. That offset is the static `/world` -> `/map` transform.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pedroexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/51367/pedroexe/) on 2020-04-09**:
Do you know how can I find out the values to use in the `/world` -> `/map` static transform once the pcd is generated?

**Comment by [ttezy](https://answers.ros.org/users/162322/ttezy/) on 2023-07-14**:
Hi Josh, I have same question as above. May I know how can I measure the values from world to map? Like 14771 84757 -39 0 0 0 in demo data and 0.0001 0 0 0 0 0 in BorregasAve.